# Need help regarding this if else program in PHP

Tags: php, html, xampp

```
<HTML>
  <body>

<?php
echo "<H4>Are you a Male</h4>"
 ?>
<form action ="ifstat.php" method ="post">
  Enter Please: <input type="text" name="val1">
  <input type ="submit" >
  <input type ="reset">
</form>

<?php
  $isMale=$_POST["val1"];
if($isMale =="y" || "yes"){
  echo("You are a Male");
} elseif($isMale =="n" || "no") {
  echo("You are a female");
} else{
  echo("Invalid entry");
}

?>
</body>
</html>
```

So, this is my program code. I always keep on getting You are a Male as the output even though I type in "n" or some other value rather than y. What's wrong with the code here?

Here is the photo of the output https://i.stack.imgur.com/Fpk5U.jpg

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to change your condition formatting from `if($isMale =="y" || "yes"){` to `if($isMale =="y" || $isMale =="yes"){`

```
<HTML>
  <body>

<?php
echo "<H4>Are you a Male</h4>"
 ?>
<form action ="ifstat.php" method ="post">
  Enter Please: <input type="text" name="val1">
  <input type ="submit" >
  <input type ="reset">
</form>

<?php
  $isMale=$_POST["val1"];
if($isMale =="y" || $isMale =="yes"){
  echo("You are a Male");
} elseif($isMale =="n" || $isMale =="no") {
  echo("You are a female");
} else{
  echo("Invalid entry");
}

?>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

In your `if` statements....

```
if($isMale =="y" || "yes" ){
```

the `|| "yes"` isn't valid and will always (in this case) evaluate to true.

You also don't check if anything has been entered before processing this, so normally you would do a check of if something is set (i.e. has the forma been submitted) and then do the processing...

```
<?php
if (isset($_POST["val1"])) {
    $isMale=$_POST["val1"];
    if($isMale =="y" || $isMale =="yes"){
       echo("You are a Male");
    } elseif($isMale =="n" || $isMale =="no") {
       echo("You are a female");
    } else {
       echo("Invalid entry");
    }
}
?>
```